# Daemon app to fetch list of events from personal microsoft account

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have created a web app in past to access calendar events from ADD user's calendars. It worked fine, Now I want to create a **daemon app that can fetch the calendar events** of my personal outlook account or from account of people from my organization. 
I **followed this section of microsoft graph api docs** : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview

I could only get all user details present in my Azure active directory but I am unable to fetch calendar events.
In my **parameters.json** file. I mentioned my endpoint as : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/events

The official docs(link given above) told that we cannot access the web API which require 'incremental consent'. I want to know can I access calendar events from **daemon apps as a background service** using MS graph api. If yes, **please provide my any links or resource**
to do so. I tried searching on stackoverflow also but couldn't find any resource or doc which I can use.

Your help would be really appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

To use client credential flow, you need to add **application permissions** in your registered application in Azure portal, and this permission need admin consent.

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[Get access without a user.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP,  except I'm using the dotnet core daemon template project. I already have Application permissions for Calendars.Read and Calendars.ReadWrite. Granted admin consent already. Template project works correctly for the default call to get user info, but when I try to get events with this call it fails: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my-user-id}/calendar/events. Failure response is ResourceNotFound "Resource could not be discovered".